# RR implementation with different arrival time

Tags: c++, operating-system

I have a project which I have to implement Round Robin algorithm in c++.
The inputs are the value of quantum, arrival times and burst times.
I wrote a code which gives me the correct output when the arrival times inputs are in ascending order. for example:

```
process   arrival time    burst time
 p0           0               3
 p1           1               8
 p2           2               6
 p3           4               4
 p4           5               2
with quantum=3, it gives the correct answer of:
avg waiting time: 9.2
avg burst time : 13.8
```

but when the input isn't in ascending order the outputs are wrong as follow:
ascending order. for example:

```
process   arrival time    burst time
 p0           2               6
 p1           5               2
 p2           1               8
 p3           0               3
 p4           4               4
with quantum=3, it gives the wrong answer of:
avg waiting time: 8.4
avg burst time : 13
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help me to find the problem and fix it.
my code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct Process {  
    int id;            // Process ID
    int at;            // Arrival time
    int et;            // Execution time
    int rt;            // Remaining time
};

int main() {
    int n; // Number of processes
    int quantum; // Time quantum

    // Get input from user
    cout << "Enter the number of processes: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the time quantum: ";
    cin >> quantum;

    // Create a queue to store the processes
    queue<Process> processes;

    // Get input for each process
    cout<<"arrival times should be in ascending order:"
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Process p;
        cout << "Process " << i  << ":\n";
        cout << "Arrival time: ";
        cin >> p.at;
        cout << "Execution time: ";
        cin >> p.et;
        p.rt = p.et;
        p.id = i + 1;
        processes.push(p);
    }

    
    int current_time = 0;
    int tat = 0;
    int wt = 0;

    while (!processes.empty()) 
    {
        Process current_process = processes.front();
        processes.pop();

        if (current_process.rt <= quantum) {
            current_time += current_process.rt;
            tat += current_time - current_process.at;
            wt += current_time - current_process.at - current_process.et;
            current_process.rt = 0;
        } else {
            current_time += quantum;
            current_process.rt -= quantum;
            processes.push(current_process);
        }
    }

    // Calculate average turnaround time and average waiting time
    double avgtat = (double) tat / n;
    double avgwt = (double) wt / n;

    // Output results
    cout << "\nAverage Turnaround Time: " << avgtat << endl;
    cout << "Average Waiting Time: " << avgwt << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a queue which processes the elements sequentially irrespective of the arrival times. Since you want to process the elements with earlier arrival times, you might want to use a data structure that inherently orders the processes by arrival times (such as Priority Queue).

```
bool Compare(const Process &a, const Process &b) {
    return a.at > b.at;
} 
std::priority_queue<Process, std::vector<Process>, decltype(&Compare)> processes(Compare);
```

Moreover, you would need to update the arrival times whenever you insert the `current_process` back into the queue. This will make sure the newly added process would be ordered based on the new arrival time rather than the old.